# Srcset not working on IPhone's Safari

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML for a logo:

```
<img src="logo.png" srcset="logo-1x.png 1x, logo-2x.png 2x"/>
```

When I try this on IPhone's Safari the image is not displayed.

What might be wrong?

Comment: which iOS version are you using it?

Comment: I am using iOS 10.2

Comment: Are you sure that the additional images (logo-1x.png, logo-2x.png) exist?

Comment: Yes they do. It was the first thing I checked

Comment: Yes, I am facing the same issue. If you find any solution kindly update here. Thanks.
This issue mainly persists in iPhone safari.